# How to use colors in vuetify

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I know I can import colors so I can use deep-purple lighten-4 in JS, how would I actually do that in the Vuetify theme section below? Do I need to add a `Vue.use(colors)` ?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.css'
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.use(Vuetify, { theme: {
  primary: '#ee44aa',
  secondary: '#424242',
  accent: '#82B1FF',
  error: '#FF5252',
  info: '#2196F3',
  success: '#4CAF50',
  warning: '#FFC107'
}})

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Comment: Why would you do it in `theme`? I think `theme` color variables only serve for `color` attribute. Classes are classes.

Comment: The colors you are importing from vuetify is an object. You can actually log it to see the colors.

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/style/theme):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: colors.blue.darken4,
    secondary: colors.amber.lighten2
  }
})
```

Any theme color you don't specify inside the theme object is just given its default value by Vue.

Comment: This way of accessing the built-in colors does not work anymore (at least not for me). I've been looking for a solution for an hour by now, but it seems that I will have to stick with hard coded hex colors. I'm starting to really consider giving up on Vuetify, it feels a mess.

Answer (score 1):

just use the color="" <- then your desired color ex.

```
<v-btn color="success">Success</v-btn>
```

here is my sample pen for further more example

https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1010

Comment: This only works if the component supports it... v-container for instance does not support it.